# Changing part of folder name

Tags: string, matlab

I wish to remove part of folder's name and in a loop
for example, i have hundreds of folder name like abc_123, dsf_321, so on, and I want to remove everything after the underscore (_) include the underscore itself. The names I am able to store in a structure let's say 500 X 1 struct and each of the name are something_numbers

I don't want to change the name of folders physically, only the names in the 500 x 1 struct in the workspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to keep only the wanted part. I'm assuming the names are contained in a cell array of strings:

```
>> names = {'abc_123'; 'dsf_321'}; %// cell array of strings
>> result = arrayfun(@(n) regexp(names{n}, '^[^_]*', 'match'), 1:numel(names))
result = 
    'abc'    'dsf'
```